# Openlayers-3, can't get attributes from a WMS layer

Tags: openlayers, wms, fields-attributes

I have an osm map and a WMS from mapserver in Openlayers-3. I am trying to display some attributes from WMS "emprises" layer according to this example. But The window is empty : I just see "Feature1234:'' ". 
I have add PropertyName in the event map.on, but dont'know how to call/write it in the iframe part...if I am in the right direction !
WMS request is enabled (template) in the mapfile and works fine with Qgis.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="/proj4js-2.3.14/dist/proj4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<div id="info">&nbsp;</div>

<script type="text/javascript">   

var view = new ol.View({
      projection: new ol.proj.Projection({
      code:'EPSG:2154',
      units: 'm'
        }),
      center: [681845, 6606361],
      zoom: 6
    });     
    var wmsSourceEmprise = new ol.source.ImageWMS({            
          url: 'http://10.3.1.51:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\\OSGeo4W\\apache\\htdocs\\fond_mapserver_ol3.map',
          params: {'LAYERS': 'emprises',
                    //'CRS': 'EPSG:2154',
                    'FORMAT': 'image/png'},
          serverType: 'mapserver',
          extent: [93501.1, 6044342.00, 1248133.25, 7115784.50]

        });

     var wmsLayerEmprise = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: wmsSourceEmprise
        });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: ({
            collapsible: false //ceci ne fonctionne QUE si un fond OSM est appelé !!
                })
            }).extend([
        new ol.control.ScaleLine(),
        new ol.control.MousePosition({
                coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
                projection: 'EPSG:2154',//juste à l'affichage
                className: 'ol-mouse-position'
            })
        ]),
    layers: [
       new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM() //couche osm
        }),
     wmsLayerEmprise,
    ],
    view: view
  });

      map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
    var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
    var url = wmsSourceEmprise.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:2154',
        {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/plain',
        'propertyName': 'numope'});
    if (url) {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
          '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';       
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Does proj4js know about EPSG:2154?

Comment: Yes. The line is missing hère but does exist in the original one.